Slick crausel css is breaking and removing css class from code when i am trying to purge css in gridsome project
I tried using Purgecss to remove unused CSS. I have used

"@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "3.0.0"

and whitelisted all dynamic classes on Node 18x version.
Implementation is done but while building the application purgecss removed all slick-related classes even though I have whitelisted all classes. Any suggestion as to why it is breaking or how to fix?
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './src/**/*.vue',
        './src/**/*.js',
        './src/**/*.jsx',
        './src/**/*.html',
        './src/**/*.pug',
        './src/**/*.md',
    ],
    whitelist: [
        'body',
        'html',
        'img',
        'a',
        'g-image',
        'g-image--lazy',
        'g-image--loaded',
        'p',
        'h1',
        'h2',
        'h3',
        'h4',
        'h5',
        'h6',
        'div',
        'header',
        'footer',
        'aside',
        'nav',
        'company-carousel',
        'slick',
        'slick-slide',
        'slick-list',
        'slick-slider',
        'slick-track',
        'slick-center',
        'slick-cloned',
        'slick-prev',
        'slick-arrow',
        'slick-initialized',
        'slick-active',
        'slick-current',

    ],
    extractors: [
        {
            extractor: content => content.match(/[A-z0-9-:\\/]+/g),
            extensions: ['vue', 'js', 'jsx', 'md', 'html', 'pug'],
            // Treat every word in the bundle as a CSS selector
      defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
        },
    ],
}

I want slick carousel-related classes to be removed as they break the UI.

I have a few bad news so far:

Gridsome is dead
PurgeCSS is dead
slick-carousel is based on jQuery and weights 10.3kb + 29.4+kb from jQuery, just for a carousel
the current LTS of Node.js is v22

Good news tho:

you could use NuxtJS, Quasar or even Vitesse if you want to rebuild something similar to Gridsome, even AstroJS could somehow replace it too
Purge CSS is still alive, even tho nowadays we tend to not remove those classes but build only the ones with need with CSS frameworks like TailwindCSS because we realized that it was quite some un-necessary work and that it might lead to issues like yours
even if slick-carousel could still be used, consider some alternatives like the ones you could find here, not all of them are great but you have some choice at least
bumping Node's version might not be the most difficult process if you only need to go from v18, nvm after reading your other question here (aka starting from Node v10), I recommend starting with something brand fresh like Nuxt3.

